# Diagnose and correct problem with home built power supply

Tags: power-supply, pwm

I built a 3.3/5/12/25V power supply from a Macintosh G4 API1PC36 power supply using [Daniel Haertle's project description](https://haertle.ch/tinker/ps/). I placed a switch between the PwrOn line and GND and a LED between 5V and GND. I used a \$27\Omega\$, 10W wire wound resistor from the 3.3V/sense line to GND so the power supply does not go into standby mode and I wired 3.3V, 5V, 12V and 25V lines to banana plug ports mounted on the body of the power supply. To try to ensure the wires can handle the power used, the 3.3V, 5V and 12V lines are triple wires. See Figure 1. [image: Figure 1]

I want to use the power supply to power a 12V 100W halogen microscope light with a [PWM dimmer](https://www.ebay.ca/itm/353687068520) between the two to control the luminosity. The power supply works fine with the halogen lamp directly connected to the 12V line, see Figure 2. [image: Figure 2]

With the PWM between the power supply and the lamp, the power supply switches itself off if started with the PWM set to anything less than about 90%. It does not switch off if started with the PWM set high, but does switch off when I start to turn the PWM down, see Figure 3.[image: Figure 3]

If I put a \$1.2\Omega\$ incandescent lamp on the 3.3V line then the 12V line is fine with the PWM dimmer through the PWM's full range. See Figure 4.[image: Figure 4]

If I put a \$30\Omega\$ resistor on the 3.3V line then the PWM dimmer only works over the top 3/4 of its range, but power supply shuts itself down when the PWM is in the bottom quarter of its range. See Figure 5.[image: Figure 5]

I have previously built [a similar power supply for a 12V 100W halogen microscope lamp](https://www.photomacrography.net/forum/viewtopic.php?p=282062#p282062) from a Seasonic SS-300TFX PC power supply which works fine with the PWM and a 12V 100W lamp.  In that case, following [DroneBot Workshop's instructions](https://dronebotworkshop.com/atx-bench-supply/) I put a \$18\Omega\$ wire wound resistor on the 5V line as the constant load to prevent the ATX going into standby mode. On the API1PC36, I did try putting the \$1.2\Omega\$ lamp on the 5V line as a load but this behaved basically the same as Figure 3.

- What is causing this behaviour? Is it something related to the [frequency of the PWM experienced by this Arduino user?](https://forum.arduino.cc/t/noise-from-power-supply-when-using-high-wattage-and-pwm/208608)?
- What further data can I gather to diagnose the problem?
- Do I need to change the resistance I put on the 3.3V/sense line to a lower value?  I would like to keep the power consumed by the 3.3V/sense line as low as possible.
- Is there better solution than changing the resistance of the 3.3V/sense line? Is there a circuit I could put between the power and supply and the PWM to make them work more smoothly together? What would the appropriate circuit design be?

Comment: This has been done? >You can turn on the power supply by connecting the green cable (PwrOn) to ground (one of the black cables). But the power supply will immediately go to stand-by, leaving only pin 1 (+5Vsb) and pin 14 (+25Vsb) under voltage. To get full power you need to have a minimum load of approximately 300 mW at pin 6 (+3.3V sense), thus we will put a resistor there. So now that you know how to get it to work, let's do it.

Comment: Yes, I have put the 300 mW load on the 3.3V line and put a switch connecting the PwrOn line to ground.  That has all been done.

Comment: What does the power supply do if there is nothing connected to 12V? Realise the power supply already has capacitors and the dangers associated with the modifications you’ve done to the power supply. Is all the wiring suitable for the maximum current the psu can deliver?

Comment: When nothing is connected to the power supply's 12V line, I can detect 3.3, 5, 12 and 25V on each of those lines.  The power supply is rated to provide 17A on its 3.3V line, 20A on its 5V line, 16A on its 12V line and 4.2A on its 25V line.  I can connect the 12V line directly to the 12V 100W bulb and the power supply and it powers the bulb fine so I know it can give 8A no problem.  The problem happens when I put the PWM dimmer between the power supply and the lamp.  I will test the wires and report back

Comment: All the wires can handle the 12V 8A.  When I have the PWM between the power supply and the lamp, have the PWM turned all the way up and turn the power supply on, the lamps lights up fine.  When I start to turn the PWM **down** then the  power supply switches itself off.

Comment: In contrast, a similar setup I built from an old Seasonic SS-300TFX desktop computer power supply works fine with the same PWM between it and the bulb for the entire range of the PWM's output.

Comment: Try putting a load on 5V or 3.3V.

Comment: If I put a 2.75A load on the 3.3V line then the 12V line is fine with the PWM dimmer through its full range.  If I put a 0.363A load on the 3.3V line then the PWM dimmer only works over the top 3/4 of its range, but the bottom end of the PWM range shuts the power supply down.  So I think maybe I will go back inside and try some smaller resistances on the 3.3/sense line.

Comment: Please embed a schematic.

Comment: Agreed, adding a schematic would likely help get this question re-opened.

Comment: Post a schematic.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance.  I will draft some schematics and include them.

Comment: I'm having trouble finding a schematic of either the power supply or the PWM.  Without schematics for these components any schematic I draw will just be a simple circuit with black boxes for these components.  Since the issues are inside or between these devices, I wanted to check if you all would still think it worth drawing such a simple diagram.

Comment: Yes, please draw as complete a diagram as you can describing your system.  It is understandable that you can't flesh out everything, include everything you can.

Comment: Do these diagrams help?